# What are the pros and cons of mixing data with metadata?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

Let's say I have a table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  col1 int,
  col2 int
);
```

and a "metadata table" classifying these attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
 attribute varchar,
 description varchar
);
```

So sample data might be:

t1:

```
col1  | col2
------+------
 4    |   6
```

t2:

```
attribute   | description
------------+--------------
 col1       |  first column
 col2       |  second column
```

What are the pros and cons of using this approach? It certainly makes me uncomfortable but I can't put into words any solid objections.

Edit: it makes me uncomfortable because this design tends towards an Entity-Attribute-Value data model where everything may as well be stored in one table, i.e. the data model no longer captures as much meaning. I'm trying to quantify how much of a problem this really is.

Comment: Why does it make you uncomfortable?  What schema would make you feel comfortable?

Comment: This is a part of db server's job. You don't have to store mata data.

Comment: There are many basic Q&A about EAV. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Also, pros & cons are off-topic. But you don't clearly say what you mean by "this approach". What is your example an example of? And if you don't state clearly you can't research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are describing is *Entity Attribute Value* ([EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) or possibly *row modeling*.  Search on these terms.  You will find that there are a few advantages and many, many disadvantages.

Storing metadata in your data model's repository is good.  Modeling a metadata repository in your schema is almost certainly unnecessary and unhelpful.